# Script to work with multiple excel workbooks in parallel

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am using vbscript (.vbs file) to perform read/write actions into excel.

The script opens an existing excel file and reads/writes data into it.

If there is only one excel file open then there are no problems.

However, when the script is running, if i open another excel file and focus on this newly opened file, then the script fails and exits.

i am reading/writing using the handle to the workbook. sample is below.

```
Set xlobj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set wbobj = xlobj.Workbooks.Open(filename)
For iRow = FIRSTROW To LASTROW 
    With wbobj.Sheets(sheetname) 
        If .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)) = "FREE" Then 
            .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) 
            .Range("D" & CStr(iRow)) = vbNullString 
        Else 
            .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
        End If 
    End With 
Next
```

Need your help if there is a way to make the script work even when user is working on a different excel workbook and/or if there are better options to go about it.

thanks.
B

Comment: You're might consider showing the rest of the script... the `wbobj` looks correct but there may be other issues which you haven't exposed.

Comment: @DavidZemens, providing the snapshot of the main part of the script which performs the read/write 

    `Set xlobj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`
    Set wbobj = xlobj.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    For iRow = FIRSTROW To LASTROW
    With wbobj.Sheets(sheetname)
       If .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)) = "FREE" Then
           .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
           .Range("D" & CStr(iRow)) = vbNullString
           ...
      Else
          .Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      End If
     End With
    Next
...

Comment: Code belongs in the body of the question. It is very illegible in comment section...

Comment: Do you require this file to be *visible* to the user while the script is running?

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't modify other already opened workbooks, as it explicitly opens a particular workbook and places a handle to that workbook in a variable. However, you should avoid attaching to an already running Excel instance (`GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`) unless you have a reason to do so. For the code you posted it'd be better to create a new instance (`CreateObject("Excel.Application")`) and terminate it when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Have your code create and use its own instance of Excel without making that visible. You code would close that Excel instance when it is done (remember to do that in any terminating error handlers as well)

That way there's no interference with user's activity.